# How can I make roaming in wireless AP network?

Tags: wireless-access-point

Now I want to make roaming in wireless AP network. I use 3 different SSID and password. For example, SSID names are 1, 2, 3. I use SSID which is 1. When my SSID 1 is less strength, I want to use a strong strength form of SSID and not change my SSID. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your SSIDs, you are really relying on your client ( laptop, phone, etc) to leave the wireless network its in, in favor of a stronger network. This can cause problems because of your client's ability to hold onto a network despite its weak signal strength.

I am not sure of your reasoning to use different SSIDs. If you renamed all SSIDs to match with matching security and channels as well as any other settings you may have, your clients will have an easier choice jumping to a stronger AP in the same network, than what it would think is a new network.

Hope this helps